# Converting text into a date not working in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a piece of text I need to transform into a date:

"12/28/20 10:44 PM"

Any of the usual tricks are not working to get sheets to recognize this as a date.

I've made progress parsing out the date and time into separate cells but it still won't factor in the AM PM part.

Is there a quick way to convert to a date for this type of format?

Comment: What are the "usual tricks" you tried? How is the raw data getting into your spreadsheet? Are you trying to process one date-string or an entire column of them (or entire row of them, or both)? It would be most helpful if we could see your setup and your failed attempts via a link to an actual sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)"; "$2/$1/20$3")*1
```

[image]

then:

[image]

Comment: I get an error "Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But '28/12/2020 10:44 PM' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

Comment: @SarahMadden can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I can't as it's an internal company doc but I recreated the sheet on my personal account and your formula works perfectly. Which is even more bizarre.

Comment: @SarahMadden can you check what locale you got in your company's sheet? https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKxJg.png

Comment: Ireland for both

Comment: @SarahMadden try: `=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+).+", "$2/$1/20$3")*1`